# ASP.Net Core react deploy to IIS as application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis

As title.
I am developing ASP.Net core project with react.js, and deployed the project to a physical folder in my computer.  Assume that my IP is a.b.c.d,  I want to deploy it as application under default web site,  and set a virtual path point to the physical folder where I deploy my project.  That is, I want to show my project result when I open a browser and key in http://a.b.c.d/MyvirtualPath inside my address bar.
I've tried a way that to set PUBLIC_URL but I didn't see anything on my browser,  and what I found about deploying onto IIS is to publish as a website, and that is not what I want.
Could someone guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deploy a React application under the default website, you should not use a virtual directory but add an application under the default website:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Another point to note is that if IIS wants to host asp.net core applications, you need to install .NET Core Hosting Bundle. For more information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).**

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see anything in my browser. I thought I may have something wrong but no errors shown in Chrome DevTools.  The bundle is installed, and I've added the application.

Comment: Forget it, I just think that the way to add application to IIS for ASP.Net core is different from the way for ASP.Net traditional web form or older MVC.  Thank you.